# Filter mediator not working Properly in WSO2 EI 6.6

Tags: wso2, wso2-enterprise-integrator, wso2-esb

I'm trying to handle the response in the out sequence by using filter mediator with condition as (Vin number Updated Successfully) if it's satisfy Then block needs to be excluded but instead of Then block the else block is executed so Please tell me what did I mistaken in the below mentioned code. Thanks!

```
 <outSequence>
        <log level="custom">
            <property expression="json-eval($.)" name="===Response from COMS==="/>
        </log>
        <log level="custom">
            <property expression="json-eval($)" name="ComsResponse"/>
        </log>
        <property expression="json-eval($.ComsResponse)" name="Response" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
        <filter regex="Vin number Updated Successfully" source="$ctx:Response">
            <then>
                <payloadFactory description="Form Response Payload" media-type="json">
                    <format>{"StatusCode":"$1","Message":"$2"}</format>
                    <args>
                        <arg value="200"/>
                        <arg value="Updated Sucessfully"/>
                    </args>
                </payloadFactory>
            </then>
            <else>
                <payloadFactory description="Form Response Payload" media-type="json">
                    <format>{"StatusCode":"$1","Message":"$2"}</format>
                    <args>
                        <arg value="400"/>
                        <arg value="Unable to Created or Vin Number already exist"/>
                    </args>
                </payloadFactory>
            </else>
        </filter>
        <respond/>
        <property description="HTTPStatusCode" name="HTTP_SC" scope="axis2" type="STRING" value="200"/>
        <property description="HttpMessageType" name="messageType" scope="axis2" type="STRING" value="application/json"/>
    </outSequence>
```

[image: Log]

Comment: Can you show us the actual response, and the value of the property named Response so we know what you are trying to match with the filter?

Comment: Hi @ophychius! I attached a log screenshot above, please take a look at it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The property ComsResponse is probably empty.

```
<property expression="json-eval($.ComsResponse)" name="Response" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
```

The json-eval statement is looking for a ComsResponse element/key within the message. This does not exist as the result of just $. is only a string.

So currently the filter is testing the regex against an empty string. Try setting the Response property as follows:

```
<property expression="json-eval($.)" name="Response" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
```

For more details on the json-eval function check the [WSO2 documentation.](https://docs.wso2.com/display/EI600/JSON+Support#JSONSupport-AccessingcontentfromJSONpayloads)